# didAddSubview not being called

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

my `didAddSubview` is not being called.

This is what I am doing.

In my viewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
  SomeView *view = [[SomeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0,    CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame))];
  [self.view addSubview:view];
}
```

Where my `SomeView` is a UI view (.h file)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DyteMeetingView : UIView
@end
```

in which I have `didAddSubview` like this

```
- (void)didAddSubview:(UIView *)subview{
    [super didAddSubview:subview];
    [self someFunc];
}
```

I placed debugger in `didAddSubview` but the debugger never reaches here and hence   `[self someFunc];` is also not called.

Since `didAddSubview` is a lifecycle method for UI view, I am also not calling it from anywhere.

Can someone help me in figure out the concept I missed out on/what I could be doing wrong?

PS: I don't have any xib file for UIView.

PS: Intentionally added swift tag as well since there isn't large chunk of code and I am confident that swift developers would be able to understand the question/code and might be able to help me out.

Comment: Someone marked the question to be closed. If you could let me know the reason for marking the question as close, I will try my best to update the question and fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`didAddSubview` in `SomeView` will be called when a sub view is added *to an instance of `SomeView`*, but that isn't what you are doing here. You are adding a `SomeView` as a subview of another view.

You want [`didMoveToSuperview`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622629-willmovetosuperview?language=objc); in this method you can use the `superview` property of `self` to identify the view that it moved to.

Answer (score 0):

The `didAddSubview` will be called in `viewController.view`, instead of your `SomeView`, because you using `viewController.view.addSubview(subview)`